# How to access session in class library .Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

is there a way to access `HttpContext.session` in a class library? (im using .Net Core 5)
I have the `configuration` all set up and also using `microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` but im still unable to access the session variables.
If there is no way to do that whats the best way to perform actions that require the current User's ID/Identification?

Comment: you may want the so-called `IHttpContextAccessor` - it's the recommended way to access `HttpContext` in the services/classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @King King answered, you could inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into the class.

**Step 1 Add Session service**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddSession();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); 

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

    {
        ...
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        ...
    }
```

**Step 2 Access Session in custom class**

```
public class SessionTest
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public SessionTest(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void setSession()
    {
        _session.SetString("Test", "Hello World!");
    }

    public void getSession()
    {
        var message = _session.GetString("Test");
        ...
    }
}
```

**Step 3 access session via custom class**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SessionTest session = new SessionTest(_httpContextAccessor);
        session.setSession();
        session.getSession();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this work if the class library is used in EF Core? I've implemented this, but the IHttpContextAccessor  doesn't get passed through